# How to properly set up the projection with libgdx for 2D?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I just started with libgdx, coming from pure opengl-es, and I wanted to properly setup my screen for a simple 2d game. I stumbled upon 2 problems:

- What method should I use: glu.gluOrtho2d(), use Orthographic camera, or something else
- What should I pass into these methods?

With the second I mean if I should somehow set up the projection to be the same as the resolution (0,0 bottom-left and 320,480 top-right) and I set the projection in the resize() method, or can I better have it in a way that I for example specify `width = 20, height=width*ratio` since I have to deploy it for android, which means a lot of different screen sizes and ratios.

I hope my question makes any sense, but i'm rather confused at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link with one solution (using ratio like you described)

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25685.0